# Asp.Net Core MVC How to handle The request matched multiple endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm working on app with recipes.
I'm wrote delete recipe method and this worked fine but then had to add method which delete photo from recipe.
Working on Core 3.1.1 with Api's

I'm getting this error when I try to have 2 "Delete" methods
[image]

My code:

```
namespace RecipesApp.API.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/users/{userId}/recipes/{recipeId}/photos")]
    [Route("api/users/{userId}/recipes")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RecipesController : ControllerBase
    {




// http://localhost:5000/api/users/{userId}/recipes/{id}
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteRecipe(int userId, int id)
        {


        }


  [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePhoto(int recipeId, int id)
        {



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Route` annotation must be unique on the class definition, and is mainly used to prefix the controller path. The `Http*` annotations go on the controller public methods, their value represents the unique path assigned to each one.

Combining both (`Route` and `Http*`) you will get the full template path assigned to your method. According to this, your code must look like this:

```
namespace RecipesApp.API.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("/api/users/{userId}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RecipesController : ControllerBase
    {

        // /api/users/{userId}/recipes/{id}
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteRecipe(int userId, int id)
        {
            //
        }


        // /api/users/{userId}/recipes/{id}/photos
        [HttpDelete("{id}/photos")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePhoto(int recipeId, int id)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method DeletePhoto isn't working because recipeId is missing, i need path: // /api/users/{userId}/recipes/{id}/photos/{recipeId}

Comment: I changed to : [HttpDelete("{recipeId}/photos/{id}")] and now this is working as i wanted. Problem is solved. Thank you for the answer!